# Using huggingface fill-mask pipeline to get more than 5 suggestions

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, huggingface-transformers

The below lets me get 5 suggestions for the masked token, but i'd like to get 10 suggestions - does anyone know if this is possible with hugging face?

```
!pip install -q transformers
from __future__ import print_function
import ipywidgets as widgets
from transformers import pipeline

nlp_fill = pipeline('fill-mask')
nlp_fill("I am going to guess <mask> in this sentence")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again this is an unfortunate shortcoming of the "under construction" documentation.

If you look closely at the [parameters of the `FillMaskPipeline`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.FillMaskPipeline) (which is what `pipeline('fill-mask')` constructs, see [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.pipeline)),
then you will find that it has a `topk=5` parameter, which you can simply set to a value of your liking by specifying it in the `pipeline` constructor:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

nlp_fill = pipeline('fill-mask', topk=10)
```

Comment: As a side note, I want to add that having ten suggestions will usually  result in very low confidence scores for the further suggestions, but I am sure you are aware of that ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add that the parameter was changed to `top_k`.
It can be passed to each individual call of `nlp_fill` as well as the `pipeline` method.